# Was Peter Parker, in both the original comic book and in the movies, bitten by a male spider?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man

I would like to know if Peter Parker, both in the original comic book and in the movies, was bitten by a male spider.  I am assuming that it was always a male spider that had bitten him, because if a female spider had bitten him, then Peter's body would likely had been altered in a strange/undesired way.

Was Peter Parker, in both the original comic book and in the movies, bitten by a male spider?

Comment: The Marvel origin comic does not specify.  I do not know if it was ever specified at any other point in the run...but it definitely wasn't specified in *Amazing Fantasy #15*.

Comment: Well, if your premise is that the spider bite would cause the generation of sexual characteristics, and he didn't grow pedipalps (male spider sexual organs) either, then perhaps your premise is flawed.

Comment: “if a female spider had bitten him, then Peter's body would likely had been altered with in a strange/undesired way” — because that’s what happens when _real_ female spider bites give people superpowers 

Comment: On the one hand, the male is much smaller than the female in many spider species, so the odds are that Peter Parker's spider, being large, was a female. On the other hand, male spiders do not have a Y chromosome, just a single X chromosome compared to the females' two X chromosomes. On the third hand, none of this makes any sense in context.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedronwhat is large for one species may be small for another; while in most spider species sex determination is through X0, it is not universal among spiders; and in many species the male is larger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> then Peter's body would likely had been altered with in a strange/undesired way.

I do not believe that it would matter, for two reasons.

The science nerd aspect reason is that sex and its expression in spiders has very little to do with sex and expression in mammals. The last common ancestor between spiders and humans probably lived no later than 518 million years ago. We have as much in common with spiders as we have with mollusks and even tardigrades!

But the real, most important reason is: mostly no one cares.

Stan Lee had said time and again that he did not know science any more than the regular folk. One of the best examples of how he did not let boring interfere with his ideas comes from his autobiography (*Amazing! Fantastic! Incredible! A Marvelous Memoir*). At some point he describes the creative process that led to the Incredible Hulk:

[image: "I'll have him get hit by the rays of a gamma ray bomb!" "What are gamma rays?" "No idea, but you've gotta admit they sound good!"]

Stan Lee and his closest colleagues' creative process was based a lot on [The Rule of Cool](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool):

> The limit of the Willing Suspension of Disbelief for a given element is directly proportional to its awesomeness. Stated another way, all but the most pedantic of viewers will forgive liberties with reality as long as the result is wicked sweet or awesome.

Face it: just like a gamma ray bomb would disassemble all of Dr. Banner's molecules rather than granting him super strength, being bitten by a radioactive spider would give Peter Parker a radioactive wound rather than granting him a plethora of spider related powers.

Then again, the whole sexual characteristics due to the gender of the spider becomes a very minor thing when you consider what both male and female spiders have in common. If Stan Lee were to be really pedantic about arachnid biology, then Spider-Man would be less like the web-head we love and more like how America Chavez imagined he should be, emphasis mine:

> **Strange:** We have experience with the Multiverse. Most recently, there was an incident with Spider-Man...
> **America:** With what Man?
> **Strange:** Spider-Man. He has the powers of a spider.
> **Wong:** Hence the name.
> **America:** Gross. Does he look like a spider?
> **Strange:** No. More like a man.
> **Wong:** Climbs walls, shoot webs.
> **Strange:** Yeah. Bingo.
> **America: Out his butt?**
> **Strange:** No. Maybe. I don't know.
> **Wong:** Ew.
> **Strange: Honestly, I hope not.**
> **America:** Super weird.